# Are these two phrases the same?

Tags: usage

> *Guillaume fait tout ce qu'il peut pour faire oublier son erreur*

=

> *Guillaume tente de se rattraper le coup (mais il s'enfonce).*

?

G tries/tried to do what he was supposed to do as opposed to
G did something wrong and is now trying to make it up (more of an apology or apologetic gesture than a real solution).

Answer (score 2):

Your second sentence is incorrect. It should be either

> Guillaume tente de rattraper le coup.

or

> Guillaume tente de se rattraper.

See [the definition for *rattraper*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rattraper) (1. and 7. for our context).

These sentences have a similar global meaning: Guillaume is doing his best to make up for his mistake. However, we could see a small sublety:

- *Faire oublier son erreur* --> Try and make other people forget about your mistake by doing a lot of good things, whether or not these things are related to the mistake.
- *Se rattraper / Rattraper le coup* --> Try and make actions related to the mistake in order to limit its effects / consequences.

For instance:

> Guillaume a trompé sa femme : c'est impardonnable. À présent, il fait tout ce qu'il peut pour lui **faire oublier son erreur** : il l'aide à la maison, organise des voyages avec elle, s'est inscrit pour une thérapie de couple...

and

> Guillaume a oublié d'acheter un cadeau à sa belle-mère pour son anniversaire. Heureusement, il a **rattrapé le coup** en apportant le dessert et un beau bouquet de fleurs !

Comment: merci pour l'éclairage.